# tmux command not working when called by ssh

Tags: ssh, tmux, daemon

I want to build an interface, that, using ssh and tmux will be able to start/stop daemons.

My approach to start the daemon was:

```
tmux new-session -s myDaemonID -d /path/to/daemon/exec /path/to/daemon/config
```

stopping the daemon is as simple as:

```
tmux send-key -t myDaemonID C-c
```

(I need to send C-c, becose juste killing the session wouldn't make my daemon unsubscribe properly.

This works great, now I want to move on the network. We can here assume that path to the deamon and it's config are valid on the remote machine.

I noticed that, when started locally, I can kill my deamon using

```
ssh localhost tmux send-key -t myDaemonID C-c
```

However, I cannot manage to start it remotly. Doing so wont work, and I have no log/message/code that tells me what happens:

```
ssh localhost tmux new-session -s myDaemonID -d /path/to/daemon/exec /path/to/daemon/config
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what is not working? What command did you try that did not work, and what was the error message?

Comment: the very last command in my question returns without error message, yet the session is not active and the daemon is not running

Comment: You can try using `tmux -v ...`. It will create 2 files `tmux-*` in the current directory of the command. This log is very verbose and not very comprehensible but may give a clue as to why it fails. You could also try `ssh -t` to use a pty, but I dont think it should need one.

Comment: @meuh Nice call! Using `tmux -v` I managed to see that the issue is with loading a shared library. ssh→tmux→deamon might not call my bashrc (where I update LD_LIBRARY_PATH) at any point